# Getting the address location of variable

Tags: c#

In `C#` how can you get the address of a variable without using the `unsafe` keyword.
I do not want to change the address or access it, just have its location.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without using `unsafe` methods

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without using the `unsafe` keyword since you'd need to explicitly get the pointer to the variable to get its address. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcbcf4ta(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just wondering.... why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to pin the object before extracting its address. Otherwise, the GC is free to move it around.

```
object variable = new object();
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(variable, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr address = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

Normally you would only do this in scenarios requiring some type of unmanaged interop. However, even then there is rarely a need for this type of manual manipulation.

Answer (score 17):

You can't.
And for good reason, because the address is not fixed. It can - and will - be moved around by the memory management of the CLR.

Answer (score 7):

Since .NET moved variables in managed memory around all the time, you need to "pin" the variable, then get its location with `GCHandle`:

```
static void Main()
{

    string myVar = "This is my string";

    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(myVar, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr pointer = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle);

    Console.WriteLine(pointer);

    handle.Free();

}
```

However, I believe this actually *moves* the original variable to a *new* location referenced by the `GCHandle`, and it doesn't work for all types - only [blittable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx) types.